# Bug en iteración while de Java

Tags: java, while

El planteamiento del problema es este:

*Implemente mediante la clase String, una aplicación que cuente el número de vocales de un texto.*

La aplicación ya fue creada y logra satisfacer los requisitos solicitados. Sin embargo, a pesar de ser una aplicación simple, siempre integro una sentencia While que engloba a toda la lógica de la aplicación para que al final de la ejecución de esta, siempre permita poder repetir el proceso. 
El código es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio1capitulo4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio1Capitulo4 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String C;
    int X, TC, A, E, I, O, U, TV;

    X = 1;

    while (X == 1)
    {
         A = 0;
         E = 0;
         I = 0;
         O = 0;
         U = 0;
         TC = 0;
         TV = 0;

         System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a la que desea calcular el número de vocales: ");
         C = Leer.nextLine();
         TC = C.length();

          for (int i = 0; i < TC; i++)
          {
              if(C.charAt(i) == 'a' || C.charAt(i) == 'A')
              {
                  A = A + 1;
              }
              else if(C.charAt(i) == 'e' || C.charAt(i)=='E')
              {
                  E = E + 1;
              }
              else if(C.charAt(i) == 'i' || C.charAt(i)=='I')
              {
                  I = I + 1;
              }
              else if(C.charAt(i) == 'o' || C.charAt(i)=='O')
              {
                  O++;
              }
              else if(C.charAt(i) == 'u' || C.charAt(i)=='U')
              {
                  U++;
              }    
         }
         TV = A + E + I + O + U;     
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras A: " + A);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras E: " + E);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras I: " + I);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras O: " + O);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras U: " + U);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras vocales: " + TV);
         System.out.println("\n¿Desea evaluar otra palabra? 1-SI 0-NO");
         X = Leer.nextInt();
    }
}
```

El problema radica en que luego de ingresar el último dato, el de evaluar una nueva palabra, el ciclo efectivamente se repite pero no me permite ingresar una nueva palabra a pesar de que este proceso esté dentro del ciclo While. 
Esta es la muestra de la salida: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error es bastante sencillo el `nextLine` está obteniendo el `enter` que se da después de ingresar el valor de `X` en la línea final de su código. para solucionar agregue un `Leer.nextLine()` después del `X = Leer.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para cuando usas while que dependen de un valor usas *do-while* en resumidas cuenta ejecuta el cuerpo una vez y luego evalua la condición del while, es un poco diferente al *while*. Te recomiendo leer las diferencias.

Así quedaría el código

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio1Capitulo4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String C;
        int X, TC, A, E, I, O, U, TV;

        X = 1;

        do{
            A = 0;
            E = 0;
            I = 0;
            O = 0;
            U = 0;
            TC = 0;
            TV = 0;

            System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a la que desea calcular el número de vocales: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            C = entrada.nextLine();
            TC = C.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < TC; i++) {
                if (C.charAt(i) == 'a' || C.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                    A = A + 1;
                } else if (C.charAt(i) == 'e' || C.charAt(i) == 'E') {
                    E = E + 1;
                } else if (C.charAt(i) == 'i' || C.charAt(i) == 'I') {
                    I = I + 1;
                } else if (C.charAt(i) == 'o' || C.charAt(i) == 'O') {
                    O++;
                } else if (C.charAt(i) == 'u' || C.charAt(i) == 'U') {
                    U++;
                }
            }
            TV = A + E + I + O + U;
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras A: " + A);
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras E: " + E);
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras I: " + I);
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras O: " + O);
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras U: " + U);
            System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras vocales: " + TV);
            System.out.println("\n¿Desea evaluar otra palabra? 1-SI 0-NO");
            Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);
            X = opcion.nextInt();
        }
        while(X == 1);
    }
}
```

Quiero mencionarte también que cambie la forma en como se obtiene la palabra y como se lee la opción. Con el código original al seleccionar 1 (después) de ingresar la palabra y procesarla el bucle se repetía y no te pedía la palabra.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo la solución a tu problema, solo realice unas pequeñas modificaciones para tener mas organizado el código, pero en esencia es la misma lógica que tienes, espero te sirva.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Ejercicio1Capitulo4{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader tec = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String C;
    int X;

    do{
       System.out.println("Selecciona una Opcion: \n"
               + "1.- Contar Vocales de una Palabra \n"
               + "2.- Salir"); 
       X = Integer.parseInt(tec.readLine());
       switch(X){
           case 1:
               System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a la que desea calcular el número de vocales: ");
               C = tec.readLine();
               if(!C.equals("")){
                  ContarVocales(C); 
               }
               break;
           case 2: break;
       }       
    }while(X != 2);

  }

private static void ContarVocales (String palabra){

    int TC, A, E, I, O, U, TV;

     A = E = I = O = U = TC = TV = 0;



         TC = palabra.length();

          for (int i = 0; i < TC; i++)
          {
              if(palabra.charAt(i) == 'a' || palabra.charAt(i) == 'A')
              {
                  A++;
              }
              else if(palabra.charAt(i) == 'e' || palabra.charAt(i)=='E')
              {
                  E++;
              }
              else if(palabra.charAt(i) == 'i' || palabra.charAt(i)=='I')
              {
                  I++;
              }
              else if(palabra.charAt(i) == 'o' || palabra.charAt(i)=='O')
              {
                  O++;
              }
              else if(palabra.charAt(i) == 'u' || palabra.charAt(i)=='U')
              {
                  U++;
              }    
         }
         TV = A + E + I + O + U;     
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras A: " + A);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras E: " + E);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras I: " + I);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras O: " + O);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras U: " + U);
         System.out.println("\nCantidad de letras vocales: " + TV);
         System.out.println("******************************************* \n");

}


}
```